# .net webservice and simultaneous access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to understand basic flow in a .net webservice.
Is the service instantiated again and again for different client connections? If I have a static class/members are they shared across? How is api concurrency maintained?

I guess my question is the application context/memory/address space shared across different requests (from say different users) or somehow the requests are sandboxed?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is [instancecontextmode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Static memebers are shared within a process.
If instancecontext mode is not single then specify concurrency attribute. 
Please refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx) before proceeding.